# how to add a variable inside of a label in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In a normal print statement, I am able to put in a variable inside the statement like :

```
x=1
print("x is equal to" x)
```

But how would I be able to write the same thing in tkinter?

```
x=2
label1 = Label(text="x is equal to " x)
```

that's what my line of code looks like right now. any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `text="x is equal to "+str(x)`.

Comment: Or `text=f"x is equal to {x}"` in Python 3.

Comment: btw make sure you have ur tkinter window specified inside of your label widget

Comment: also you have to use commas or `+` to avoid  errors in your `print` and `Label` please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `x` a `str` so as to avoid concatenation of `str` and `int` error.

```
x=2
label1 = Label(......,text="x is equal to "+ str(x))
```

or you can make it a str in the first itself

```
x = '2'
label1 = Label(.....,text="x is equal to "+x)
```

or you can also use formatted string (`f'...'`) in python 3.x and use {} to dynamically enter values

```
x = 2 
label1 = Label(.....,text=f"x is equal to {str(x)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x=4
y=5
label = Label(self, text="x is {}, y is {}".format(x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, typecast your variable to a `string` using `str()`, then concatenate it to the title string as follows:

```
marks = 505
label = Label(root, text="I got "+str(marks)+" marks.")
```

I hope that it may help you......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer doesn't add anything new to the previous answers. This may be problematic when answering other questions. Therefore, please avoid answering questions with answers that answer the OP's question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @TheMaker, I'll try to avoid this.